# How would I get my accelerometer to not move my node when the device is straight and not tilting?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer

I have a game where when I tilt to the left and right to move my node. But when I keep the device straight I would like it to stop the node and also add an image of my node so there  isn't a grey and white checkerboard. How would I do this? As you can see in my code I use SKTexture to change the nodes image and the velocity to move my node. How would I change the image when the device is straight and not tilting and for the node not to move? Thank you!

```
       func addTilt() {

       if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) {
        (data, error) in

        if(data.acceleration.x < -0.05) {  // tilting the device to the right
            self.heroNode.accelerometerActive == true
            self.heroNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -250, dy: 0)
            self.heroNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroNode1")

        } else if (data.acceleration.x > 0.05) {  // tilting the device to the left
            self.heroNode.accelerometerActive == true
            self.heroNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 250, dy: 0)
            self.heroNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroNode2")
        }
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could add an `else` in your current logic that handles when the X acceleration is greater than -0.05 and less than 0.05, which is mostly upright with only a little tilt in either direction.

Also, you should use `=` for assignment instead of `==`, which tests equality and has no effect on the value of your `accelerometerActive` property.

And, if it were me, I'd keep the code cleaner by ditching the extra parenthesis since in Swift you don't need them.

```
if motionManager.accelerometerAvailable { // No parenthesis
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue()) { (data, error) in

        if data.acceleration.x < -0.05 {  // tilting the device to the right
            self.heroNode.accelerometerActive = true
            self.heroNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: -250, dy: 0)
            self.heroNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroNode1")

        } else if data.acceleration.x > 0.05 {  // tilting the device to the left
            self.heroNode.accelerometerActive = true
            self.heroNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 250, dy: 0)
            self.heroNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroNode2")

        } else { // straight
            self.heroNode.accelerometerActive = false
            self.heroNode.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0) // No velocity
            self.heroNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heroNode3") // Image when straight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said but when my device is straight it doesn't stop or change the image.

Comment: Also when I use "=" instead of "==" I get an error saying cannot assign to the result of this expression.

Comment: Then you can't assign to it because it's read only.  Can you post more code, maybe a repo on GitHub?

Comment: Thats all the code I have for the tilting and it works except for when it is straight

Comment: I set the speed = 0 in the else statement and it works now.